# How to handle "empty_url_error" when setting up Next.js project with Microsoft Azure AD?

Tags: authentication, next.js, configuration, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to set up Microsoft Azure AD authentication, and I feel like I have filled everything out correctly (I wans't sure what to share regarding the keys and company name, so I wrote what's supposed to be there, rather than accidentally giving out confidential information). I keep getting a "empty_url_error" and this [github link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/src/error/ClientConfigurationError.ts)  didn't give me much to work with.

## My config.js

```js
export const config = {
    
    auth: {
        clientId: "Application/Client ID",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/My tenant ID", 
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000",
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", 
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
      }
    };
   
    export const loginRequest = {
     scopes: ["Scope"]
    };
```

## My index.js

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { config } from '../config'
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser'
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'flowbite-react'

class index extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {}
    };

    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    this.PublicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: config.clientId,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
        authority: config.authority
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
      }
    });

  }

  async login() {
    try {
      await this.PublicClientApplication.loginPopup(
        {
          scopes: config.scopes,
          prompt: "select_account"
        });
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true })
    }
    catch (err) {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        error: err
      });
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.PublicClientApplication.logoutPopup();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="viewpoer" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
          <meta httpEquiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge' />
          <title>Title</title>
          <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/images/favicon.ico'></link>
        </Head>

        {this.isAuthenticated ?
          <p>Succesfully logged in</p>
          :
          <p><Button onClick={() => this.login()}>Log in</Button></p>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default index;
```

I've looked through my files to find out where this URL could or should be, and I've tried different links in the authority field, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue, by renaming these properties in my config.js and in my index.js

- clientId to client_id
- authority to tenant
- redirectUri to redirect_uri

I did this because I read somewhere in the documentation for the PublicClientApplication library, that it should be written like that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).